# Mobile devices: Click on a Font Awesome icon

Tags: jquery, mobile, click, font-awesome

I have a font-awesome icon

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-3x custom-close" id="proyect-close"></i>
```

which is clickable:

```
$('#proyect-close').click(function(){
  $('#proyect').slideUp('slow', function(){
    $(window).trigger('resize.px.parallax');
  });
});
```

It works fine on desktop computers, but on mobile phones (I have tried both iPhone and Android) it is as there is no click event at all, I keep touching the font awesome icon and nothing happens.

I added `display:block;` or `display:inline-block;` CSS to the font awesome because I found that on researching, but did not work either. Just in case, this is the CSS:

```
.proyecto .custom-close{
  display: inline-block;
  color: white !important;
  position: absolute;
  right:10%;
  margin-top:-5px;
  min-width:28px;
  min-height:42px;
}
```

If anybody knows why this is happening, and what is the trick to fix it, I would be really thankfull.

Comment: What is the rest of the CSS code applied to this element ? I' thikingn it might be helpful to force width and height, but maybe that's already the case ?

Comment: @LaurentS. That's all the custom CSS applied to this element. I just tried setting height and width to it, but still did not work. Any other idea?

Comment: there must be other CSS as there is no mention of icon-font in this... what you're actually clicking when using an icon-font is a pseudo-element `::before` or `::after` , and it's that element that needs to have some width and height. Please do a jsFiddle reproducing your problem.

Comment: It does have other css, but only the font-awesome css, not customized by me. I don't know if this can be reproduced in a JSFiddle as it only fails on mobile devices, in desktop computers the click event works fine.

Comment: If you are using jQuery Mobile try replacing "click" event with "vclick" event.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
The trick was change this

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-3x custom-close" id="proyect-close"></i>
```

for this

```
 <a class="custom-close" id="proyect-close"><i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-3x custom-close"></i></a>
```

I tried using a span instead of an anchor, but somewhy it only works with anchor. I also had to add some css:

```
a.custom-close{
  z-index:2;
}
i.custom-close{
  z-index:1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly tell Safari it's a clickable element.

In your css add a class:

```
.fa-clickable {
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
}
```

and then add the class to the clickable fontawesome icon:

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-up fa-3x custom-close fa-clickable" id="proyect-close"></i>
```